# How to re-render views using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to re-render all the views present on my page.I have Header, Footer and Body view. In Header view i have a dropDown in which user can select the Language Preference. On clicking on language prefrence all the view should be re-render. Is it Possible in Angular?

In BackboneJs i simply call the render function again on that particular event. Is there some same kind of functionality provided by AngularJs?

Thanks in Advance

Header Template (language Prefrence Dropdown Code)

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
        Language Preferences<b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-manual">

        <li id="English" ng-click="englishConversion()">English</li>
        <li id="French"  ng-click="frenchConversion()" >French</li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

is there any inbuilt function which i can call in englishConversion and frenchConversion to re-render the view/views?

Comment: Do you inject the texts into the view by using scope variables?

Comment: yes. i injected the template in the directive. My code Look like this

'angular.module('mycomponent', [])
  
  .directive('headernav', function() { 
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { },
   controller: function($scope, $element) {
     },
      templateUrl:'/static/tmpl/headernav.html',
      replace: true
    };
  })'

Comment: Then I think *re-rendering* is the wrong approach (especially with angular). Just have localized strings in the scope and switch a language marker. The rest will be done by angular. I'll add an answer shortly.

Comment: why re-rendering is the wrong approach in Angular @Yoshi

Comment: Because I don't think that's the right way to handle such stuff in angular. The view is constantly re-renderd on data-change (two-way-data-binding). So there is seldom, or rather, there should seldom be any need to trigger it manually. If you handle the data correctly, angular will take care of the rest.

Comment: My data is wrapped around a function.Like This `{{trans.t(data.Button_Name)}}` where trans is `$scope.trans = window.polyglot;` and polyglot is `$.getJSON('/static/locales/' + _locale + '.json', function(data) {window.polyglot = new Polyglot({phrases: data});})`

Comment: As you already use a function for tranlation there is even less need to re-render stuff. You should really add any relevant information to your question (including code). Also try setting up a [http://plnkr.co/](http://plnkr.co/) so we can see what your code is doing.

Comment: It rather seems that your function works asynchronously and that you don't tell angular that the data has changed. If that's the case there solutions to this problem. But you really have to add more code.

Comment: @yoshi thanks for the help. I will try somechanges in my code. If it don't work then I will change my implementation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the [angular-getText libary](http://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/) ,

Or you can $[compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) the HTML using angular again. You can simply do like this,

```
var content=angular.element('#translatedContent');
var scope=content.scope();
$compile(content.contents())(scope));
```

Comment: ok that is for internationalization, But I am using PolyGlotJs for this. Any Idea how to render-views in Angular?

Comment: How do you translate the content , is it from the server side ?

Comment: No it is on client side.we just wrap the string values in templates inside polyglot.t('String').And we first have to initialize the Polyglot. For more check this link http://puigcerber.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/backbone-js-internationalization-with-polyglot-js-by-airbnb/

Comment: I think you can `$compile` the HTML again. See my edit

Comment: this worked but i got an issue the data which is in ng-repeat just is now doubling of it's initially value. like on the first time i have 2 tabs after exectuing this function my tab count increase to four.

Comment: Ah ok. Then keep the content as a template. keep the html somewhere hidden and compile that and insert it in to the #content div.